# dense_rank() order by and nulls - how to make it treat them as bottom of the ranking?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, sql-order-by, window-functions

I am using Postgresql version 9.1.9:

```
select version();
"PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf,
 compiled by gcc (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1) 4.6.3, 32-bit"
```

and I have a simple table (called Test) that has a single nullable `bigint` column (called A).  The table has the following data:

```
NULL
1
2
```

Now I want to create a dense ranking (therefore using the [dense_rank()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) function) so I do the following query:

```
select "A", dense_rank() over (order by "A" desc) from public."Test"
```

This returns:

```
NULL,1
2,2
1,3
```

Interestingly if I set up exactly the same thing in SQL Server 2008 R2 and run the same query it returns:

```
2,1
1,2
NULL,3
```

So, I am interested in who is correct but, more practically, what I want is the SQL Server behavior so, **how can I make PostgreSQL treat the null as bottom of the ranking**?

(i.e. sort NULLS as smaller than any value)

I noticed this on the dense_rank page, but it is not talking specifically about this function, but perhaps it is a clue?

> Note: The SQL standard defines a RESPECT NULLS or IGNORE NULLS option
>   for lead, lag, first_value, last_value, and nth_value. This is not
>   implemented in PostgreSQL: the behavior is always the same as the
>   standard's default, namely RESPECT NULLS. Likewise, the standard's
>   FROM FIRST or FROM LAST option for nth_value is not implemented: only
>   the default FROM FIRST behavior is supported. (You can achieve the
>   result of FROM LAST by reversing the ORDER BY ordering.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [**`NULLS LAST`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) clause to modify how  `NULL` values are sorted. Does exactly what you asked for:

```
SELECT "A", dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY "A" DESC NULLS LAST)
FROM   public."Test"
```

Not just for window functions, for `ORDER BY` *anywhere*.

Postgres does the right thing out of the box. Since `NULL` sorts last in ascending order, it should come first by default when the order is inverted.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Comment: great - thanks very much!  (I thought postgresql might be the correct one, by the way :-))